# Customize Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I use Visual Studio 2012 and I want to customize the start interface when I open it in order to see in the right side the toolbox and properties tabs and in the left side the tab with the list of folder and in the main screen in the center the code I type.

How can I make it?

Comment: Have you tried dragging and dropping the windows to where you want them? VS remembers the layout.

Comment: Yes I tried you suggestion and it works but I can't find how to appear the list with the created folders.

Comment: Which folders do you mean? Visual Studio has no Explorer-like window where you can simply browse files, but it does have the Solution Explorer, which contains all folders and files that are part of your solution. To drag it separately, drag and drop the tab in the window rather than the title bar.

Comment: To be clear I refer to box of Solution which contains the folder and the files which we work. Hope it helps to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily, just drag selected windows (e.g.: solution explorer window) and drag it into icon indicated left side of IDE[image: put cursor here]

and so on...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could I ask you how you get the window with the folder when we create a new file?

Comment: at the top menu select: VIEW -> SOLUTION EXPLORER (the first one).. It should be display at right side, or if there is try to find at right side bookmark Solution Explorer..
Or you want open Windows folder with that file? If yes, only right mouse button at folder -> Open Folder in File Explorer.. or click at project at Solution Explorer and that's same